# How to boot on Mac OS X? Emergency

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, mac, refind

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a partition of 50 GB.My main OS is El Capitan.I don't have rEFInd installed and now i cannot boot on my main partition even while pressing option key.I can also unmount or eject my Macintosh HD but i don't know if that's safe.Any help anyone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is with Mac OS. You'll be better suited to ask on [UNIX.se]

Comment: [Reset PRAM and SMC](http://thenextweb.com/lifehacks/2010/12/04/how-when-why-to-reset-the-pram-smc-on-your-mac/#gref). If booting with the option key doesn't work after that then you probably have some hardware fault. [Apple#1](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204063) [Apple#2](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295)

Comment: I disagree that this is a Mac OS X problem. The problem, if I understand it correctly, is that GRUB (a program provided with Ubuntu) has taken over the boot process and is not listing an option to boot OS X. Thus, it's a bug/limitation in an Ubuntu component (GRUB). The solution may (or may not) come from elsewhere, but the cause is software provided with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have three suggestions:

- In Ubuntu, type `sudo update-grub`. That should cause Ubuntu to update the GRUB menu. With any luck, it will detect your OS X installation and create a boot entry for it. This might not work, though; the detection code should be the same as the code that ran during installation, so if it failed then, it will probably fail now. It's worth a try, though.
- Use my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on CD-R or USB flash drive (download links are provided for both) to boot. This should give you the option of booting Ubuntu or OS X. Once you've booted OS X, you should be able to use its startup disk manager to reset OS X as the default boot option. The trouble with this approach is that you'll then be able to boot OS X but not Ubuntu. This might be acceptable as a short-term solution as you work out something longer-term, though, or if you've decided you don't want to boot Ubuntu at all.
- Install rEFInd to your hard disk. You should be able to do this in Ubuntu; however, I generally advise installing from OS X on Macs. Thus, you might want to use rEFInd on a USB flash drive to boot to OS X so as to install rEFInd. One complication, though, is that El Capitan's System Integrity Protection (SIP) feature will prevent installation unless it's disabled first. See [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/sip.html) for details on how to work around this problem. (One possible solution is installing in Ubuntu, which would obviously be the easiest solution in your situation.)

Comment: Thank you very much.I tried your 3rd suggestion and i worked. :)